# Img won't be a circle

Tags: css, image

I have tried using `border-radius: 50%;`
and as well as `clip-path: circle();`.

These did not work for me. The image didn't change at all.

My HTML code for it is:

```
<div class="mother">
  <img src="C:\Users\ettol\Downloads\279844298_10220091619552880_8482562802466459283_n.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="mother"> <img src="C:\Users\ettol\Downloads\279844298_10220091619552880_8482562802466459283_n.jpg"></div>

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put just enough code into your question so we can see the problem ourselves. As it stands any answer is just a guess.

Comment: Try overflow: hidden and see what you get. My suspicion is though that you’ll want to set divs dimensions eg with fit content or a width/aspect-ratio.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you gave us, I do not find a reason for border-radius to fail you.
Anyway, I would like to recommend you to use the "Inspect" feature on your chrome browser (right-click + Inspect). This might show you whether the style is runover, or maybe used on the wrong element.
Either way, some more information might be useful to further assist you :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this.

```css
.mother {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img class="mother" src="https://picsum.photos/500">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This worked for me. In my html I wrapped a div element around my image. So it seems that’s why it wouldn’t work.